# C++ Opening file with *i pointer, Overrides in Linux but not in Windows

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, call

So I've got this program working in Windows, and I'm trying to make it also work on a Linux machine. I believe the Linux machine is running an outdated version of g++ compiler but that is out of my control. Anyway, heres my function:

```
for (vector<string>::iterator i = groups.begin(); i != groups.end(); ++i)
{
    inStream.open((*i + "List.txt").c_str());
    while (getline(inStream, next))
    {
        if (next == n) {
            memberOf.push_back(*i);
        }
    }
    inStream.close();
}
```

The issue lies with the inStream.open() call. In windows this works fine, but in Linux it seems that *i (for example lets say that *i is pointing to "Tigers") is being overridden and therefore the call is just inStream.open("List.txt"); as opposed to inStream.open("TigersList.txt");

I've tried various ways of solving this, such as setting string k = *i; which works in itself in the sense that if I call cout << k; it prints "Tigers". However as soon as I try to concatenate "List.txt" to the end it just overrides "Tigers" and I'm left with only "List.txt"

ex:

```
k += "List.txt";
k.append("List.txt");
```

etc. Nothing seems to work in Linux, however everything I've tried has the same (correct) end result in windows.

What am I doing wrong???

Edit: inStream is an ifStream object.
memberOf is another vector of strings.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but instead of the messy `for` loop using iterators, in C++ 11 try a range based `for` loop: `for ( string s : groups )  {inStream.open( ( s + "List.txt" ).c_str() );...` (Perhaps your dated compiler won't recognize this construct..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are reading `Tigers` from a file that contains Windows line endings.  If you read this file in Linux, then reading the line:

```
Tigers\r\n
```

will result in your string in memory being `Tigers\r`.  Then when you concatenate to it, even though the result actually ends up being `Tigers\rList.txt`, when you print it out then your terminal treats `\r` as carriage return and so `List.txt` overwrites `Tigers` on your screen.

Of course, opening the file fails because the filename didn't contain an embedded `\r`.

To fix this you could do one of the following:

- In Linux, make sure that the file you're opening has Linux line endings (e.g. run `dos2unix` on it)
- Update your program to look for and discard a `\r` on the end of a line that it has read from the file.

Comment: Thanks you! You're right, I was reading from a .txt file that was copied from windows. I recreated the file using linux and now it works perfectly haha